# p5.js fourier transform of mic input gives no output

Tags: javascript, fft, p5.js

I tried to analyze the frequency spectrum of the microphone input with the following code using the p5.sound library.

The output in the console is just an `array of 1024 0's`, as if their is no sound. I tested with the recorder software that came with the computer that it is capable of recording something.

So I think I am missing something between starting the recording and analyzing it, I just can't figure out what.

I imported the `p5.js, P5.sound.js, audiosynth.js` libraries, through the quickstaet bootstrap cdn, it should also load the Jquery library.

```
var mic;
var fft;
window.onload = init;

function init() {
  mic = new p5.AudioIn();
  mic.start();
  fft = new p5.FFT();
  fft.setInput(mic);
  let frequencies = fft.analyze();
  console.log(frequencies); // always an array full of 0's
}
```

Comment: I assume you would want to call `fft.analyze` after some time has passed.  As it is, there is no time to gather any data before you try to analyze it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to run the analysis when a button is pressed, or after some time has passed, or every x seconds.  Here’s a simple example of calling analyze 10 seconds after the call to init, which should give time to collect some data.

```
    var mic;
    var fft;

    function getFreqSpectrum() {
        let frequencies = fft.analyze();
        console.log(frequencies);
    }

    window.onload = init;

    function init() {
        mic = new p5.AudioIn();
        mic.start();
        fft = new p5.FFT();
        fft.setInput(mic);
        setTimeout(getFreqSpectrum, 10000); // do this in 10 seconds
    }
```